# I am unable to run any command or file of python - there is no output in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run my python code or even the simplest hellow command in VS Code's termilnal, it is just showing this:

```
C"/users/admin/document/my python file
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Can you clarify it? maybe provide a picture?

Comment: ok here is a screenshot of what's happening ,you can open the given below link of the screenshot                                           
  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-v-ONT2m2rRI/YKioAzF8vLI/AAAAAAAAJ_4/7Z9GxL1SAoInIUxKDyrEy3WGvdcj0itOwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/Screenshot%2B%252814%2529.png?authuser=0

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see any problem with it. Have you pressed 'F5' to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is more like an VS-Code question. But anyways: I believe you have to use a command to run the file, just like this:

```
py <file-path-here>
```

Example:

```py
py example.py
```

Also, maybe try installing the Python extension in VSCode.
And make sure you have Python installed correctly (check the button "add Python to path" in the first page of the Python installation setup).

If all of this does not work, make sure to select the correct Python version in VSCode by doing this:

> Go to top menu, click *view*, *command pallete*, type *Python Select Interpreter* and choose the correct version.

Also, check if the file ends with *.py* so VSCode knows that you are working with a Python file.

Since you're new here: you can support me a lot by upvoting this answer or marking this as an answer. <3 Thanls

Comment: i have done it all but its keep on showing this    https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-v-ONT2m2rRI/YKioAzF8vLI/AAAAAAAAJ_4/7Z9GxL1SAoInIUxKDyrEy3WGvdcj0itOwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/Screenshot%2B%252814%2529.png?authuser=0

Comment: Bro - what is going on wit your VSC? xD Maybe try reinstalling it. What happend to your IDE, it's just completely broken.